# Figure out a threshold percentage for predictions provide by a logistic regression machine.

Tags: statistics

I am trying to figure out a particular percentage of confidence so that I can minimize false positives and false negatives and get the most optimal result set.

Here is what I am doing...

I am currently working on a machine learning project. It is a logistic regression model and the response I am getting is categorical in nature. I have two categories rightnow. Lets say 'A' and 'B'.

During testing the machine responds with a percentage of confidence for both the labels.
Output Example:   A:0.7689     B: 0.2311

I trained my machine on 4000 data items for each classifier and predicted 200 data items (test data) and received the following kind of result:

LevelOfConfidenceRange  RightPredictionsinthisRange WrongPredictionsinthisRange

```
        50%-60%                         2                       3           
        60%-70%                         5                       0           
        70%-80%                         7                       2           
        80%-85%                         4                       1           
        85%-90%                         10                      0           
        90%-95%                         49                      4           
        95%-100%                        109                     4
```

Now, I want to figure out a threshold percentage (e.g. 87%) so that I output certain number of predictions in which correct predictions are maximized and wrong predictions are minimized and I still provide a sufficient amount of results. That is I'll be only considering the outputs predicted by the machine if the level of confidence provided by it is greater than Threshold percentage (87%) only. I'll be rejecting the results that have been predicted with a level of cofidence less than Threshold percentage.

Currently I am forming such a table and then deciding my threshold percentage.

I want to know if there is a sophisticated/proper Mathematical method to figure this threshold percentage.

I would appreciate any help!

Regards 
Savya Saachi

Comment: You have a conflict of goals, and you need to quantify how you want to resolve it. Prediction accuracy is maximized by choosing few results, and the "sufficient amount" of results is maximized by choosing many results; so far you haven't said how these goals are supposed to be compared to each other. You need to quantify what you would consider an optimal compromise between them; otherwise you don't have a well-defined mathematical problem. What constitutes an optimal compromise is determined by your setting and not by mathematics.

Comment: @joriki Thanks a lot for pointing out the confusion in this question. Let me think about this and get back to you.

Comment: @joriki I have thought about the issue you have pointed out but I am not able to digest that there isn't any method which can help us find a compromise between the two situations that is "high accuracy" and "sufficient amount" of results. If we compare this to a situation where we are designing a car and I have two parameters "fuel efficiency" and "speed of the vehicle" then there must be a particular range in which these two compromise, i.e. I have high speed and the fuel efficiency is also high.

Comment: @joriki In the results I have shown in the problem above to me 85% seems like a reasonable threshold percentage as it has reasonable accuracy and the results I am showing is also sufficiently large. According to your suggestion i need to fix atleast one variable right? So, If I fix one of these parameter like if I say that I want to show 150 results (sufficient amount) out of 200 predictions then this problem becomes easy or if I fix the number of wrong predictions I can accomodate then also I can easily find out the threshold percentage.

Comment: No, that's a thorough misunderstanding. I wrote neither that there isn't any method which can help us find a compromise between the two situations nor that you need to fix at least one variable. What I wrote is that finding a compromise between the situation is not a mathematical issue but one determined by your setting; you have to make that compromise based on what's important in your application. And you don't have to do it by fixing some value. For instance, you could maximize the ratio of the number of correct predictions to the square root of the number of predictions.